# Change 'kMDItemWhereFroms' extended attribute when saving file from chrome

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write/collect some productivity scripts before starting grad school. What I'd like to do is keep track of the context in which I've downloaded (mostly pdf) files for research... for example, fetching the original email a file was attached to.

Luckily, Mac OS X records the download URL as well as the referer URL in the files' extended attributes. However, the way google handles attachments, the orignal email URI gets lost in a series of redirects before the actual file download starts.

I'm hoping there is some Apple Script magic to correct the `kMDItemWhereFroms` extended attributes to include the URI of the page that initiated the download. I'm able to (for example) fetch the URL of the active tab with

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    get URL of active tab of first window
end tell
```

and could correct the extended attribute by executing

```
xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms NEW_URL FILENAME
```

But, what I'm missing is some way to either a). get the pathname of the most recently downloaded file to automatically run the `xattr` command with, or maybe b). create an alternate download workflow in Apple Script, or c). some other brilliant idea....?

Answer (score 0):

Save this in your Folder Actions folder and attach it to your Downloads folder.

```
    on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theFiles
    repeat with aFile in theFiles
        tell application "Google Chrome"
            activate
            set myUrl to URL of active tab of first window
        end tell

        set filePath to quoted form of POSIX path of aFile
        do shell script "xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms " & quoted form of myUrl & space & filePath

    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```